# Proving derivative equality without L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose $f^{\prime\prime}(a)$ exists. There are many proofs on this site that we then have \begin{equation*}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)+f(a-h)-2f(a)}{h^2} = f^{\prime\prime}(a)\end{equation*} but all of them seem to use either L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor's theorem/asymptotic expansion. Is there a way to do it just using the Mean Value Theorem and/or Cauchy's mean value theorem?

Comment: Why is it a "derivative inequality" and not a "derivative equation" or "identity"?

Comment: I have edited now.

Comment: How do you distinguish Taylor's theorem from the mean value theorem?

Comment: Taylor's theorem is proved using Cauchy's mean value theorem. I'm not quite sure what you're getting at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the functions $f_1(h)=f(a+h)+f(a-h)-2f(a)$ and $f_2(h)=h^2$. From Cauchy's mean value theorem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)+f(a-h)-2f(a)}{h^2} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f_1(h)-f_1(0)}{f_2(h)-f_2(0)}\\
&= \lim_{c\to 0} \frac{f_1'(c)}{f_2'(c)}\\
&= \lim_{c\to 0} \frac{f'(a+c)-f'(a-c)}{2c}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\lim_{c\to 0}\frac{f'(a+c)-f'(0)}{c - 0}+\lim_{c\to 0}\frac{f'(a-c)-f'(0)}{-c-0}\right]\\ 
&=f^{\prime\prime}(a) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

I used the fact that $c\to 0$ as $h\to 0$ and the definition of the derivative.

Comment: This is how one proves the $0/0$ case of l'Hospital's Rule using Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, That was exactly my process :D Using the definition of the derivative is also akin to l'Hopital.